# Create a point at intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, intersection

I want to create a point at the intersection of two lines as it appears on the attached image.

[image]

The red line is the stream network, and the green line is the 600m contour.
I use ArcGis 10.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool and define POINT as output type.

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.
>
> output type: POINT - Point intersections will be returned. If the
>   inputs are line or polygon, the output will be a multipoint feature
>   class.